# How to get an element node using Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm using Mechanize.

How I can obtain the element node to get a particular attribute? I have:

```
 page.form
```

And I want to get the id of that element.

I tried things like:

```
 page.form.attribute['id']
 page.form.attr 'id'
```

with no luck. I'm not interested only in the id, but in the ability to get any attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id for that would be:

```
page.form.form_node['id']
```